# Deployed Tomcat app on Openshift returns 404

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, resteasy

I've deployed my app under following url: https://migawka-hatak.rhcloud.com/,
but constantly I get a 404 status.
The same app works on my local Tomcat or Jetty. When accessing localhost:8080/ROOT/ it returns the default Openshift index page.

From the logs on openshift I can see that it's started:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Nov 05, 2014 4:14:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/openshift/5458e7d3500446ea91000597/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbosse
ws/webapps/ROOT.war
SLF4J: The requested version 1.5.8 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
47 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
53 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of threa
d: localhost-startStop-1
148 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class
org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
150 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.2.1 created.
158 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
160 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) 'Defau
ltQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
161 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initial
ized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
161 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.2.1
Nov 05, 2014 4:14:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/5458e7d3500446ea91000597/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jb
ossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 7,523 ms
Nov 05, 2014 4:14:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-127.9.148.1-8080"]
Nov 05, 2014 4:14:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7825 ms
```

I'm using quartz in the context listener, also my app is based on the RestEasy framework.
Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Does `http://yoururl.com` point to `localhost:8080/ROOT/` ?

Comment: having the same issue for past three days. Please let know if any thing to change .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved problem, by recreating app from scratch, only difference is that I've used web.xml from from tmplate instead of mine.

What is different on web.xml now:

```
 <web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">

</web-app>
```

Comment: i have re-created  my app too, but still the same problem. can you explain a little the thing about `web.xml`

Comment: Well I've taken Web. Xml file from repository created from template then adjusted it to my purpose. When I was using Web. Xml from my app it was not working -  take a look on header

Comment: can you please point me the changes that you have made (if i am not asking much), it will be very much helpful. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Sure I've used their header <web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false"></web-app>

Comment: thanks for your help. i tried this header and removed other version incompatibility now its working.